# Grub hangs on first boot, key repeating

Tags: grub2, 15.10

Whenever I boot my computer for the first time on a day the first key I press is continuously repeated causing me to have to reboot my computer before I can boot my OS.

So basically the following happens:

- My computer boots
- Grub boot menu is shown
- I press the down arrow key
- Grub moves all the way to the lowest option
- Grub no longer responds to any other key

Another example

- My computer boots
- Grub boot menu is shown
- I press the 'E' key to edit some boot options
- The boot options menu is shown and filled with 'e' characters
- Grub no longer responds to any other key

I can always solve this problem by rebooting my computer. But the next day the problem reappears!

Does anyone know what might be causing this? And how I can solve this?

I use Ubuntu 15.10. My Grub version is 2.02~beta2-29ubuntu0.3. Back when I still used Ubuntu 14.04 I also had this problem.

Comment: My first thought is a hardware issue, that when the laptop is cold, a connection is just a little off, and when it warms up the connection expands a bit. Does this happen only the first time each day you power on?

Comment: I have not yet tested this very thoroughly but generally speaking whenever I have already booted the computer once I can safely boot it again during the day. Then after I try to boot it again the next day I always run into this problem. I am not sure if it matters but I am not using a laptop. Also do you got more info about these kind of things? How can cold hardware trigger these kind of things? I do not know a lot about this side of computers.